# Get last Friday's Date unless today is Friday using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dayofweek

I'm trying to get the correct SQL code to obtain last Friday's date.  A few days ago, I thought I had my code correct.  But just noticed that it's getting last week's Friday date, not the last Friday.  The day I'm writing this question is Saturday, 8/11/2012 @ 12:23am.  In SQL Server, this code is returning Friday, 8/3/2012.  However, I want this to return Friday, 8/10/2012 instead.  How can I fix this code?  Since we're getting to specifics here, if the current day is Friday, then I want to return today's date.  So if it were yesterday (8/10/2012) and I ran this code yesterday, then I would want this code to return 8/10/2012, not 8/3/2012.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -3, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this:

```
declare @date datetime;
set @date='2012-08-09'
SELECT case when datepart(weekday, @date) >5 then
 DATEADD(DAY, +4, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @date), 0)) 
else DATEADD(DAY, -3, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @date), 0)) end
```

**result**:

```
2012-08-03
```

Example2:

```
declare @date datetime;
set @date='2012-08-10'
SELECT case when datepart(weekday, @date) >5 then
 DATEADD(DAY, +4, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @date), 0)) 
else DATEADD(DAY, -3, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @date), 0)) end
```

**result**:

```
  2012-08-10
```

Comment: I'll up-vote you and accept a week from now if all goes well.  So far, so good.  I will test each day of the week.  The top one meets my requirements.  Thanks.

Comment: @MacGyver: I have updated my query, Please check it now..and for testing you can change the date and see..

Comment: how do i customize this code on Wednesday, or any other day?

Comment: @Zeina to get other days of the week you have to know that the last `DATEADD` is subtracting from the Monday of whatever week you starting from. So the `-3` from Monday = Friday. If you want to have the previous Wednesday then you would need to change it to -5 so it would be `DATEADD(DAY, -5, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @date), 0))`because 5 days before Monday is Wednesday.

Answer (score 11):

Modular arithmetic is the most direct approach, and order of operations decides how Fridays are treated:

```
DECLARE @test_date DATETIME = '2012-09-28'

SELECT DATEADD(d,-1-(DATEPART(dw,@test_date) % 7),@test_date) AS Last_Friday
      ,DATEADD(d,-(DATEPART(dw,@test_date+1) % 7),@test_date) AS This_Friday
```

Comment: seems to me that This_Friday does not work, because today is 25.2.2016 that's mean Friday is 26, but variable shows 19.2.2016 which is same as Last_Friday

Answer (score 5):

Use this :

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, (DATEDIFF (day, '19800104', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) / 7) * 7, '19800104') as Last_Friday
```

Answer (score 4):

None of that? Try this:

```
DECLARE @D DATE = GETDATE()
SELECT DATEADD(D,-(DATEPART(W,@D)+1)%7,@D)
```

Answer (score 3):

A tested function which works no matter what @@DATEFIRST is set to.

```
-- ==============
-- fn_Get_Week_Ending_forDate
-- Author:      Shawn C. Teague
-- Create date: 2017
-- Modified date:  
-- Description:   Returns the Week Ending Date on DayOfWeek for a given stop date
-- Parameters: DayOfWeek varchar(10) i.e. Monday,Tues,Wed,Friday,Sat,Su,1-7
--             DateInWeek DATE
-- ==============
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Get_Week_Ending_forDate] (
                   @DayOfWeek VARCHAR(10),@DateInWeek DATE)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @End_Date DATE
          ,@DoW TINYINT
   SET @DoW = CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@DayOfWeek) = 1 
                     THEN CAST(@DayOfWeek AS TINYINT)
                  WHEN @DayOfWeek like 'Su%' THEN 1
                  WHEN @DayOfWeek like 'M%'  THEN 2
                     WHEN @DayOfWeek like 'Tu%' THEN 3
                  WHEN @DayOfWeek like 'W%'  THEN 4
                  WHEN @DayOfWeek like 'Th%' THEN 5
                  WHEN @DayOfWeek like 'F%'  THEN 6
                  ELSE  7
               END

   select @End_Date = 
          CAST(DATEADD(DAY,
               CASE WHEN (@DoW - (((@@datefirst) + datepart(weekday, @DateInWeek)) % 7)) = 7
                        THEN 0 
                    WHEN (@DoW - (((@@datefirst) + datepart(weekday, @DateInWeek)) % 7)) < 0 
                        THEN 7 - ABS(@DoW - (((@@datefirst) + datepart(weekday, @DateInWeek)) % 7))
                    ELSE (@DoW - (((@@datefirst) + datepart(weekday, @DateInWeek)) % 7) ) 
               END
               ,@DateInWeek) AS DATE)

   RETURN @End_Date
END
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the Friday of Last week.

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, -3 - (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7, GETDATE()) AS LastWeekFriday
```

This will give you last Friday's Date.

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, +4 - (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST-2) % 7, GETDATE()) AS LastFriday
```

Comment: it does not.  it gives 8/3/2012, not 8/10/2012, just like mine

Comment: I'm sorry my friend. I thought Last week's Friday. I corrected the query. I hope this helps.

Comment: If run Mon, Tue, Wed or Thu, this code still won't work correctly.  "SELECT DATEADD(day, +4 - (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST-2) % 7, GETDATE()) AS LastFriday".  Replace GETDATE() with a variable and you'll see.  I think to solve the logic within my question, we need a case or if statement like @joe has.

Comment: I think you didn't get a thing. The date shows based on the server from which the sql server is running on. if you change the date on the server from which the sql server database is running, this will do the trick. Try to change your system date and try the query on the local database. If you  want last monday, Tuesday. try changing the "+4" value on the query.

Comment: This will work different on different database settings, you should always try to avoid using datefirst

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert(varchar(10),dateadd(d, -((datepart(weekday, getdate()) + 1 + @@DATEFIRST) % 7), getdate()),101)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code can be use to return any last day by replacing @dw_wk, test case below use friday as asked in original questions

```
DECLARE @date SMALLDATETIME
,@dw_wk INT --last day of week required - its integer representation
,@dw_day int --current day integer reprsentation
SELECT @date='8/11/2012'
SELECT @dw_day=DATEPART(dw,@date)
SELECT @dw_wk=DATEPART(dw,'1/2/2015') --Just trying not to hard code 5 for friday, here we can substitute with any date which is friday
SELECT case when @dw_day<@dw_wk then DATEADD(DAY, @dw_wk-7-@dw_day,@date) else DATEADD(DAY,@dw_wk-@dw_day, @date) END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer I found [here](http://www.joellipman.com/articles/sql/mysql/mysql-day-of-week-ending-on-friday.html) adapted from MySQL to T-SQL that is a one liner using all basic arithmetic (no division or modulos):

```
SELECT DATEADD(d, 1 - datepart(weekday, dateadd(d, 2, GETDATE())), GETDATE())
```

---

You can do all sorts of combinations of this, like get next Friday's date unless today is Friday, or get last Thursday's date unless today is Thursday by just changing the 1 and the 2 literals in the command:

**Get next Friday's date unless today is Friday**

```
SELECT DATEADD(d, 7 - datepart(weekday, dateadd(d, 1, GETDATE())), GETDATE())
```

**Get last Thursday's date unless today is Thursday**

```
SELECT DATEADD(d, 1 - datepart(weekday, dateadd(d, 3, GETDATE())), GETDATE())
```

Comment: Be careful with this solution as it is dependent on the current value of DATEFIRST. The solution only works if the DATEFIRST is set to 7, the usual default.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same issue, and created the following example to show how to do this and to make it flexible to use whichever day of the week you want.  I have different lines in the `SELECT` statement, just to show what this is doing, but you just need the `[Results]` line to get the answer.  I also used variables for the current date and the target day of the week, to make it easier to see what needs to change.

Finally, there is an example of results when you want to include the current date as a possible example or when you always want to go back to the previous week.

```
DECLARE @GetDate AS DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @Target INT = 6 -- 6 = Friday

SELECT
        @GetDate                                                                                                                                AS [Current Date]       ,
        DATEPART(dw, @GetDate)                                                                                                                  AS [Current Day of Week],
        @Target                                                                                                                                 AS [Target Day of Week] ,
             IIF(@Target = DATEPART(dw, @GetDate), 'Yes'   , 'No')                                                                              AS [IsMatch]            ,
             IIF(@Target = DATEPART(dw, @GetDate), 0       ,               ((7 + @Target - DATEPART(dw, @GetDate)) % 7) - 7)                    AS [DateAdjust]         ,
      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        CAST(IIF(@Target = DATEPART(dw, @GetDate), @GetDate, DATEADD(d, (((7 + @Target - DATEPART(dw, @GetDate)) % 7) - 7), @GetDate)) AS DATE) AS [Result]
      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;
SELECT
        @GetDate                                                                               AS [Current Date]       ,
        DATEPART(dw, @GetDate)                                                                 AS [Current Day of Week],
        @Target                                                                                AS [Target Day of Week] ,
                           ((7 + @Target - DATEPART(dw, @GetDate)) % 7) - 7                    AS [DateAdjust]         ,
      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        CAST(DATEADD(d, (((7 + @Target - DATEPART(dw, @GetDate)) % 7) - 7), @GetDate) AS DATE) AS [NOTIncludeCurrent]
      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DECODE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DY'),'FRI',SYSDATE,NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'FRI')-7) FROM dual;
```