# Select data from today until the last 15th of month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to select a range of data from today until the last 15th (so this month or last month). How would this be done in TSQL?

Following [Get last Friday's Date unless today is Friday using T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912181/get-last-fridays-date-unless-today-is-friday-using-t-sql) it seems like I would have to make use of `DATEDIFF` at the least.

I'm considering building a date string, like:

```
set @date='yyyy-mm-15'
```

But `yyyy` or `mm` would not be able to be simply the current year/month, in case it has to look back a month/year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you what you want

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourDate > CAST((
            CASE 
                WHEN DAY(getdate()) < 15
                    THEN (CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CHAR(4)) + CAST(MONTH(dateadd(month, - 1, getdate())) AS CHAR(2)) + '15')
                ELSE CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CHAR(4)) + CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS CHAR(2)) + '15'
                END
            ) AS DATETIME)
```

**EDIT**
changed WHEN DAY(getdate()) > 15 **to** WHEN DAY(getdate()) < 15, as the results were inverted :)

Comment: I tried this, but I got one date in the result set from 11/9/2012. It should only be showing from today until 11/15/2012. Shouldn't the first case part only be from this month and not last month?

Comment: At least you have the idea on how to do it and you could work from this, but I'll have a look tomorrow ( Im from my iPhone here )

Comment: Yes I just noticed I have inverted but cannot edit from my phone, just invert the 'then' and 'else' content :-)

Answer (score 3):

Format the current date in the format `yyyy-mm-15`, convert back to date, compare to the current date and if this is later that today, subtract 1 month.

That's what I'd do in ANSI SQL... But apparently, MS SQL Server doesn't know  "interval". Well, you can make use of [DateAdd](http://www.siccolo.com/Articles/SQLScripts/how-to-create-sql-to-get-last-day-in-month.html) instead:

> DateAdd() - Returns a new datetime value based on adding an interval to the specified date.
>   Where first parameter specifies on which part of the date to return a new value: yy(yyyy) for Year, mm(m) for Month, dd(d) for Day etc.
>   For example: select dateadd(d,2,getdate()) - adds 2 days to current date and returns new date.