# Need to pass a select to a variable to pick up last friday of 6 weeks ago

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

hello I was looking to execute a stored procedure that receives variables for @startweek and @endweek.

I wanted to pass for execution that the @endweek to be the last friday of the current week and for the @startweek to be the friday of 6 weeks ago.

I have made the following for the last friday of current week:

```
 SELECT @startweek = '25 Jan 2019'
 SELECT @endweek =  DATE
FROM
  (SELECT DATE = dateadd(d, -((datepart(weekday, getdate()) + 1 + @@DATEFIRST) % 7), getdate())) a
ORDER BY a.DATE DESC
```

What I'm needing to do is to get the way to pass the @endweek value (now is hardcoded) for it to select the last friday of 6 weeks ago.

one thing that I got to work is the following:

```
SELECT friday4WeeksAgo =dateadd(ww, -4,DATE)
FROM
  (SELECT DATE = dateadd(d, -((datepart(weekday, getdate()) + 1 + @@DATEFIRST) % 7), getdate())) a
ORDER BY a.DATE DESC
```

but I wasn't able to pass this to a variable

I have the procedure written, just need to figure out how to do to pass to these variable the values that I need (@startweek and @endweek) to show the last friday from 6 weeks ago and the last friday from current week

thank you for any help

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: sorry I can't reply directly, thank you for not flagging that I wasn't quite clear with my question. I have updated now and I'll remove this comment in a little time so it doesn't spam. thank you.

Comment: you want to know how to call a procedure with these parameter ? Or do you need help in writing the procedure ? What is exact your problem/question ?

Comment: I have the procedure written, just need to know how to get the last friday from 6 weeks ago and send it to the variable, I tried to clarify this now on the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912181/get-last-fridays-date-unless-today-is-friday-using-t-sql    How were you "not able to pass this to a variable"??    Did you try `SET @MyVariable = SELECT ... {your query}` ???   What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation for last Friday is correct, but unnecessarily complicated.

```
SELECT @endweek = dateadd(d, -((datepart(weekday, getdate()) + 1 + @@DATEFIRST) % 7), getdate());
SELECT @startweek = DATEADD(WEEK, -6, @endweek)

EXEC YourProcedure
    @StartWeek = @startweek,
    @EndWeek = @endweek;
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: yes! this is exactly what I was needing, thank you very much for your help, I did started doing selects from tables and I believe that there is were I over complicated it.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
DECLARE @startweek DATE,@endweek DATE
 SET @startweek = '14 Aug 2019'
 SET @endweek =  dateadd(day,case when DATEPART(DW,dateadd(ww,-6,@startweek))>5 then 6 else -1 end - 
                 DATEPART(DW,dateadd(ww,-6,@startweek)), dateadd(ww,-6,@startweek))

SELECT @startweek AS DatePassedIn,
       @endweek AS Six_weeks_ago_Friday_Date

--dateadd(ww,-6,@startweek)/*this part get 6 weeks back, based on date pass to @startweek*/
```

Comment: By incorporating `@@DATEFIRST` into his solution, the OP is avoiding a gotcha that can happen to calculations that rely on `DATEPART`. Your results could vary if the `DATEFIRST` setting changes in the environment. You may also want to consider [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations).